# estoy tratando de insertar nuevos elementos al dom con angular

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, estoy necesitando crear un botón que me permita añadir otra linea como esta: que me permita crear esta misma linea debo de que la que ya está creada en el DOM

```
<tr>
  <td>
     <div id="texto" class="col">
        <label >Empresa</label>
        <input type="text"  id="cheoption">
     </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="col">
       <label id="texto">Años laborados</label>
       <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone" >
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

hasta el momento hice esto

```
app.component.ts

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  home = new home();
  dataarray=[];

  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.dataarray.push(this.home);
  }

  addNewRow(){
    this.home=new home()
    this.dataarray.push(this.home);
  }

}

export class home
{
  name:any;
  anos:any;
}
```

y en html hice esto: por alguna razon el ngModel no me esta tomando la configuración que ya está creado en el archivo ts, aun así me gustaría saber como poder solucionar este problema, ya que o me esta creando las lineas en el documento

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onsubmit()">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form row" *ngFor="let obj of dataarray">
      <td>
        <div class="form-group col-md-5">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="cheoption" class="form-control" name="anos" [(ngModel)]="obj.home" >
        </div>   
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="class=form-group col-md-5">
          <label id="texto">Años laborados</label>
          <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="obj.anos">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="class=form-group col-md-2"> 
            <span class="btn btn-danger">-</span>
        </div>
      </td>

    </div>
    <div class="form row">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="addNewRow()">+</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

pero me sale error cuando hago el ngModel y no me esta permitiendo ingresar los nuevos objetos
[image: debajo de ingresar otra empresa la idea es crear un boton de adicionar para que le cree los dos campos tanto empresa como años laborados]

Comment: Agrega el error del ngModel.

Comment: @crrlos amigo ya pude agregar los campos pero ahora tengo otro pequeño problema el cual voy a publicar para que me colabores porfa
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/280936/quitar-campos-del-dom