# quitar campos del Dom

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

El botón de eliminar no me permite eliminar el último registro que se creo, elimina el primer campo insertado.

En el botón HTML llamado "Quitar campos" le tengo la función `removeForm(1)` ese "1" lo que hace es que me permite dejar el primer registro que tengo en la lista de experiencia laboral,

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="estuadiciontitulo">
        <h2><label>Experiencia laboral</label></h2>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="let obj of dataarray">
    <td>
        <div id="texto" class="col">
                <label >Empresa</label>
            <input type="text"  id="cheoption" required>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="col">
            <label id="texto">Años laborados</label>
            <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone" required>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="col">
        <button type="button" (click)="addNewRow()">Adicionar campos</button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" (click)="removeForm(1)" >Quitar campos</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

cuando miro la vista y le doy agregar campo el me permite adicionar otra fila. lo que hice es que en cada campo le di orden alfabético (a,b,c,d) para distinguir que campos desaparecen a la hora de dar quitar campos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y después de darle `click` al botón "quitar campos" el me quita el primer campo que se insertó en este caso el campo "b"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me gustaría saber como debo hacer para que el botón "quitar campos" solo quite los campos comenzando desde el último creado

este es el codigo que tengo para eliminar los campos

```
addNewRow(){
    this.home=new home()
    this.dataarray.push(this.home);

  }

  removeForm(index){

    this.dataarray.splice(index,1);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.dataarray.splice(index,1);` si lo haces así le estás diciendo a la función que te elimine un elemento empezando en la posición 1, en este caso la posición 1 es el registro b. Lo que tienes que hacer es decirle que elimine el último elemento, el cual tiene su posición en `dataarray.length -1` y te quedaría así :

```
this.dataarray.splice(dataarray.length -1,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

El botón que usas para borrar campos llama a `removeForm(1)`. Es decir, eliminar el elemento que está en la posición 1. Contando con que los arrays tienen el primer elemento en la posición 0, estás borrando siempre el elemento en la segunda posición (el B). Si quieres eliminar siempre el último puedes modificar el código así:

```
removeForm() {
  this.dataarray.pop(); //pop saca el último elemento del array
}
```

Dejando el html de la plantilla así, sin parámetros:

```
<button type="button" (click)="removeForm()" >Quitar campos</button>
```

Puedes mirar la documentación de [splice y pop de la clase Array en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array#M.C3.A9todos_Transformadores_.5BMutator.5D)